# the dead of winter

Tags: winterfest

do you use this expression "the dead of winter"?
there was a sentence using that expression  meaning severe cold.
I never saw that kind expression before.

Comment: It's idiomatic of the part of winter that has the shortest amount of daylight.

Comment: @Lawrence In my experience, of the way it is used in Britain, it simply conveys an image of serious winter conditions. "It happened in the dead of winter". Nowhere is this better expressed than in the hymn by Gustav Holst *In the bleak mid winter*, performed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0aL9rKJPr4) by the choir of Kings College, Cambridge.

Comment: @WS2 Fair enough. I was perhaps overly specific in my description.

Answer (score 1):

*The Dead of Winter* is a common phrase in the English language that refers to the center/middle or the harshest period of winter. Lawrence and WS2 made reference to these issues in their comments.

The *Dead of* is also used with *the night*: **In the Dead of the Night**. [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/at-in-the-dead-of-the-night-winter) says:

> If something happens in the dead of night, at dead of night, or in the dead of winter, it happens in the middle part of the night or the winter, when it is darkest or coldest.

I would add that the relationship between *Dead* and *Winter* and *Night* is obvious. It brings to mind another phrase: ["the darkest hour is just before the dawn."](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/darkest-hour-is-just-before-the-dawn) As you may see, the timing of the [nadir](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nadir) is subjective here.